# How to pass the content of a file as multiple arguments in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, parameter

I have a file that contains data that gets updated over time (mydata). The file looks like this:

```
1 2 3
```

With this file, I want to do this (basically handle each number as a separate parameter):

```
myscript.sh 1 2 3
```

Since the data is not static but instead updated over time, I want to run this command:

```
myscript.sh "$(cat mydata)"
```

But instead I see ./myscript.sh: line 1: 1: command not found

What should I do?

Comment: And what does your script contain, since that's an error from within the script?

Comment: sqlite3 /data.db "insert into tbl1 (v1, v2, v3, timeEnter) values($1 $2, $3, DATETIME('NOW'));"

Comment: Solved! I didn't put the directive #!/bin/bash
and was running from sh instead...

Comment: Still makes me wonder what in it caused `1` to be treated as a command. I don't see process or command substitutions.

Comment: Split cat's output on IFS. `set -f; unset IFS; myscript.sh $(cat mydata)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`"$(cat mydata)"` evaluates to a string which contains the content of the file `mydata` minus any trailing newline. What you want is the list of whitespace-separated words in the file. So, for once, use the command substitution outside of double quotes:

```
myscript.sh $(cat mydata)
```

For extra robustness, turn off globbing, so that if a column in `mydata` contains one of the characters `\[*?` it isn't interpreted as a file name pattern. You may also want to set [`IFS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html#Word-Splitting) to contain the word separator characters, but the default (ASCII whitespace) should be exactly what you need.

```
(set -f; myscript.sh $(cat mydata))
```

Alternatively, you could use the `read` builtin. This reads the first line and ignores the rest (which you could do above by replacing `cat` by `head -n 1`).

```
read -r one two three rest <mydata
myscript.sh "$one" "$two" "$three"
```

Comment: And by the way - there is *robust* and there is *bugged* - there is no *extra robust.* Your recommendation is, in any case, *bugged* as it does not consider `$IFS`'s current value in either case and relies upon a shell default - *(or, it would, if it didn't contradict itself instead)* which is a default you have no way of knowing remains still in effect.

Comment: Note that the default `$IFS` is only space, tab  and newline/linefeed (and NUL with zsh), not the other _ASCII whitespace_  (vertical tab, carriage return, form feed). Some shells take `$IFS` from the environment which allows system distributors or administrators to set a different default value (though that's rarely done).

Answer (score 6):

That's typically what `xargs` is for:

```
xargs myscript.sh < mydata
```

`xargs` considers the input as blank or newline separated words where single quote, double quote or backslash is used to escape the separators. `xargs` will run the command as many times as necessary so as to avoid the limit on the size of arguments (and environment) passed to a command.

Comment: How to handle it if mydata have multiple rows? current command only take the 1st row.

Comment: @ShichengGuo, what do you mean by *row*? If you mean *line*, then as I said newline is one of the characters `xargs` treats as delimiter, so if `mydata` contains `foo bar\nbaz\n`, your command will be passed `foo`, `bar` and `baz` as arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of passing as multiple arguments, I just pass the arguments as a single array and then do whatever I want with the arguments.

```
#This is the function which takes a variable length array as an input. 
function function_call() 
{
    all_array_values=$1[@]
    a=("${!all_array_values}")
    for i in "${a[@]}" ; do
        echo "$i"
    done
}


#Here I add all the file contents to the variable named input.  
input=$(cat filename)
#In this step I convert the file contents to an array by splitting on space. 
input_to_array=(${input//' '/ })
#I call the function here. 
function_call input_to_array
```

**Testing**

I have the input file as below.

```
cat filename
1 2 3 4
5
6
7
8
```

As you can see, I have used multiple lines as well in the input for testing purposes.

Now, when I run the above script, I get the below output.

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

I change the input file to have lesser number of arguments and when I run with the lesser arguments, I get the below output.

```
1
2
3
4
```

**References**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461656/bash-how-to-pass-array-as-an-argument-to-a-function
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5257398/1742825